# how to call the collection function in model ( backbone) for amd architecture?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, amd

// file one

// how to call the choicesCollection `setnextOne` in ChoicesModel `default` function(object)

```
var ChoicesModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() { 
      // this.collection ??
      return {
        seq_id: choicesCollection.setnextOne(),
        subject: ""
      };
    },
    initialize: function() {

        console.log(this);

      if (!this.get("seq_id")) {
        this.set({"seq_id": this.defaults().seq_id});
      }
    }
});
```

// file two

```
var ChoicesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:ChoicesModel,
    setnextOne: function() {
      if (!this.length) return 0;
      return +this.last().get('seq_id') + 1;
    },
    // sort
    comparator: function(choice) {
      return choice.get('seq_id');
    }
});
```

// file three

```
var choicesCollection =  new ChoicesCollection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving some more insight into Manikandan's answer...

If you look at the backbone code you'll see the following (I've removed some bits):

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
  options || (options = {});
  _.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));
};

// List of view options to be merged as properties.
var viewOptions = ['model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName', 'events'];
```

As you can see_.pick is used to white list a sub-set of properties from the options passed in. The View prototype is then extended to bolt on these properties (if they've been passed).

In short, the following properties are automatically thrown onto your view if you pass them as options:

model, collection, el, id, attributes, className

Comment: I find the root case,my backbone version (0.9.2) is too old.In new version,`defaults` function initialize after as you said that 'list of  `model` options to be merged as properties'.

Answer (score 0):

As per the backbone [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) you should access the collection by this.collection once you added model to collection. Or you need to send collection option when you create a model.

Comment: I just want to call the collection method in model `defaults` in order to set the **auto index value**